# phpcassa - storing only one charecter values

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

i am trying to use cassandra via phpcassa and below is the code:

```
 $pool = new ConnectionPool($KS, array('127.0.0.1:9160'));
    $users=new ColumnFamily($pool,$CF);
    $users->insert_format = ColumnFamily::ARRAY_FORMAT;
    $users->return_format = ColumnFamily::ARRAY_FORMAT;
    $email='12334@asdasd.com';
    $input=array('col1' => 'val1',
                     'col2' => 'val2',
                     'col3' => 'val3','col4'=>'ladhania');
    $users->insert($email,$input);
    $row=$users->get($email);
    var_dump($row);
    echo $users->get_count('$email');
```

but the output is :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "a" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "v" [1]=> string(1) "a" } }
0
```

i would like to know

1. why isnt it storing all the 4 columns
2. why the stored columns have value of only one character
3. Is there a php client to search cassandra using solr

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're specifying [ARRAY_FORMAT](http://thobbs.github.io/phpcassa/api/class-phpcassa.AbstractColumnFamily.html#ARRAY_FORMAT) as the input format, it's expecting the columns to be like this:

```
$input = array(array('col1', 'val1'),
               array('col2', 'val2'),
               array('col3', 'val3'),
               array('col4', 'ladhania'));
```

The [alternate formats](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/examples/alternate_formats.php) example may also be useful.

> Is there a php client to search cassandra using solr?

[DataStax Enterprise has integrated Solr support](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise/search#navtop), which you can query through either the Solr API, CQL (in recent versions), or the Thrift API (e.g. phpcassa).

Comment: @AnkitLadhania you're welcome!  As a reminder, on StackOverflow, you should accept answers that solve your problem so that others will not think the question is still unsolved.